# I got problem with the terminal, HELP

Tags: command-line

Well I was using the terminal normally trying to install Pulseaudio but I didn't have success, then I closed the terminal but a few minutes later I open it again to run an installation, the terminal open and isn't showing me that text with my name and the computer name.

I already tried to reset and clear but nothing happen.

I tried to write a few commands but it keeps empty and nothing happen.

[Update] after try all options below I didn't have success, To solve the problem I downloaded the "Terminator" this one https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com.br/ and new terminal works fine.

Problem Solved For Now.

Look at the print screen

[image: screen]

Comment: Well did you hit <ENTER> ?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Comment: When you say 'closed' you clicked 'x', not the minimize?

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl + z or ctrl + d.

Comment: Yes .............

Comment: I tried it now didn't work.

Comment: why not restart your system?

Comment: I already restarted the computer and the terminal keep empty.

Comment: can you do this from another shell (like xterm). cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak

Copy the skeleton .bashrc file over yours:

cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

then try restarting the normal shell.

Comment: Can you get a shell with CTRL+ALT+F3?

Comment: I didn't even know about Xterm I already have it opened, can you explain it better?

Comment: I tried to do it now, and it opened a login black page I tried to login but it said my login was invalid.

Comment: Is it possible to open `xterm` (instead of `gnome-terminal`)?